# Need to propagate properties from an API call to all Apache Camel routes with timers without excessive API calls

Tags: java, properties, apache-camel, integration

I'm utilizing Apache Camel and facing an intricate situation. I retrieve certain properties via an API call and aim to use these properties across all my other routes. Initially, I employed caching to manage this, but it no longer serves its purpose.

```
<route id="initializeProperties">
    <from uri="timer://initTimer?repeatCount=1"/>
    <to uri="http4://127.0.0.1:8093/GETSINGLETONASJSON?Singleton=PROP"/>
    <setProperty propertyName="PropData">
        <simple>${body}</simple>
    </setProperty>
    <log message="Data initialized: ${property.PropData}"/>
</route>

<route id="anotherRoute">
    <from uri="timer://someTimer?fixedRate=true&amp;period=30000"/>
    <setHeader headerName="config">
        <simple>${property.PropData}</simple>                        
    </setHeader>
    <!-- ... other route configurations ... -->
</route>
```

I attempted to use a property, but each of my other routes uses a timer. As a result, they don't seem to be able to access this property. An alternative I found was to use the "direct" component to invoke the route making the API call each time. However, I have around fifteen routes that operate rather frequently. This would translate to making multiple API calls per second, which is not feasible.

Is there any credible alternative or solution within Camel's built-in components or patterns that would allow me to propagate these properties to all routes without bombarding the API?